# Angular2 setTimeout and cleartimeout dynamically /multiple

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout, cleartimeout

```
public timerId;

delete(id){
   this.timerId=id;
   this.timerId = setTimeout(()=>{
  //some logic
  },5000);
}

undo(id){
  this.timerId  = id;
  clearTimeout(this.timerId);
}
```

i want to delete multiple ids and undo(clearTimeout particular) id with delay. using this logic but failing help needed. Angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use an Observable:

```
private subscriptions = {};

public delete(id) {
    const subscription = Observable.of(null)
        .delay(5000)
        .subscribe(() => {
            // logic here
        });
    this.subscriptions[id+''] = subscription;
}

public undo(id) {
    const subscription = this.subscriptions[id+'']
    if (subscription && !subsciption.isUnsubscribed) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.subscriptions[id+''] = null;
}
```

Comment: tryd dis way.... facing the same issue in this code also.. for single scenario its working fine, that was working in setTimeout and clearTimeout as well But multiple delete call with delay and undo multiple its not working. only last(latest) undo cal works.

Comment: Thank u .. it worked.   making it constant it acts as unique rite?? and why is this done? this.subscriptions[id+''] = subscription; pls can u explain?

Comment: If a variable never gets reassigned 'const' should be used always.. That's best practice.
We set a field in the subscription object named after the id to access the subscription later by the id. That's all.

So after setting, the subscriptions object looks like:
{
    1: subscription
}

And we can access the subscription by the id later.